# Is the a circuit building software that can accept a music file as the input?

Tags: audio, simulation, spice

I am trying to manipulate the output of an audio file. I have been using such things as high and low pass filters and I would love to use a simulation software such as PSpice to simulate before building.

I would need the audio input to be split into the right, left and mono channels to be used as input signals to my circuit.

Is there any software out there than can do such a thing?

Comment: Ltspice does wav files

Comment: you will want to get Audacity and learn. IF you can imagine what is needed to split the spectrum into bands or comb filter, It can do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to build the filters and such from components, many circuit simulators including the popular [LTSpice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/#LTspice) can input and output WAV files. For example, [in LTSpice](http://www.linear.com/solutions/6087) and [in Microcap](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/news/fall2011/wav.shtm).

However, if you do not want to define the filters with transforms or you simply want knobs to twiddle, use an audio program like [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) (simple) or a full DAW like [Reaper](http://www.reaper.fm/) (free and very capable), which will let you use existing plugins or build your own plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try Tina-TI. You have to use a wav file for this purpose. Take a general voltage source, go to its settings and there you have an option to input a wav file as the signal.

If you have an mp3, you should convert it to wav using Audacity.

Comment: With Audacity you have dozens of parametric filters and Spectrum Analyzer . A virtual recording studio for crossfading, stereo echo filtering and mono splitting.

Comment: Use LT spice, you can do the same thing

Comment: LTspiceIV and Audacity are completely different.

Comment: Splitting tracks and conversion of formats could be done in Audacity. Even though you can apply direct filters from there, if you want to test the circuit-model of the filters and all, you have to use LTSpice or TINA.

Comment: @tonystewart ltspice does the same thing as Tina TI, not as Audacity

Comment: right............ unless one really has a good algorithm , audacity is for experimenting with a studio synth then realize the transforms used by design.  I once fixed a 20 mode bass synth that used 20 SSI CMOS in the 70's and all the part numbers were sanded off.  funky flanger , echo , reverb and many others.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt LTSpice can perform the custom audio processing of Audacity to separate mono into pseudo-stereo.

[image]

Choosing a design can later be done in LTspice after you trying different audio spectral effects.